# Getting error while include multiple controller in Angular js

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular js. I am trying to build a web apps with Angular and Rails from [thinkster](https://thinkster.io/angular-rails/). I have made a index page on which i had load the home template, home template carries two field i.e title and link of the post and a submit button. On submitting the title and link is added to an array and displays it on the home page. Now i have added another another template that is post, in which their is facility to comment on a particular post but after including the post template and controller my app is not running. Help me in solving the problem.

index.html file contain :

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Flapper News</title>
  <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="angular-ui-router.js"></script>
  <style> .glyphicon-thumbs-up { cursor:pointer } </style>
</head>
<body ng-app="flapperNews" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <ui-view> </ui-view>
    </div>
  </div>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="/posts.html">
  <div class="page-header">
    <h3>
      <a ng-show="post.link" href="{{post.link}}">
        {{post.title}}
      </a>
      <span ng-hide="post.link">
        {{post.title}}
      </span>
    </h3>
  </div>

  <div ng-repeat="comment in post.comments | orderBy:'-upvotes'">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"
      ng-click="incrementUpvotes(comment)"></span>
    {{comment.upvotes}} - by {{comment.author}}
    <span style="font-size:20px; margin-left:10px;">
      {{comment.body}}
    </span>
  </div>

  <form ng-submit="addComment()"
    style="margin-top:30px;">
    <h3>Add a new comment</h3>

    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text"
      class="form-control"
      placeholder="Comment"
      ng-model="body"></input>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
  </form>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="/home.html">
  <div class="page-header">
    <h1> Flapper News </h1>
  </div>
      <div ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy:'-upvotes'">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"
          ng-click="incrementUpvotes(post)"></span>
        {{post.upvotes}}
        <span style="font-size:20px; margin-left:10px;">
          <a ng-show="post.link" href="{{post.link}}">
            {{post.title}}
          </a>
          <span ng-hide="post.link">
            {{post.title}}
          </span>
        </span>
        <span>
          <a href="#/posts/{{$index}}">Comments</a>
        </span>
      </div>

      <form ng-submit="addPost()"
        style="margin-top:30px;">
        <h3>Add a new post</h3>

        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Title"
            ng-model="title"></input>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text"
          class="form-control"
          placeholder="Link"
          ng-model="link"></input>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
      </form>

</script>

</body
```

app.js contain :

```
angular.module('flapperNews', ['ui.router'])
.config([
'$stateProvider',
'$urlRouterProvider',
function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/home',
      templateUrl: '/home.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl'
    });

    $stateProvider
    .state('posts', {
      url: '/posts/{id}',
      templateUrl: '/posts.html',
      controller: 'PostsCtrl'
    });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
}])

.factory('posts', [function(){
  var o = {
    posts: [
      {title: 'post 1', link: 'link1',upvotes: 5},
      {title: 'post 2', link: 'link2',upvotes: 2},
      {title: 'post 3', link: 'link3',upvotes: 15},
      {title: 'post 4', link: 'link4',upvotes: 9},
      {title: 'post 5', link: 'link5',upvotes: 4}
    ]   
  };
  return o;
}])

.controller('PostsCtrl', [
'$scope',
'$stateParams',
'posts',
function($scope, $stateParams, posts){
    $scope.post = posts.posts[$stateParams.id];
    $scope.addComment = function(){
      if($scope.body === '') { return; }
      $scope.post.comments.push({
        body: $scope.body,
        author: 'user',
        upvotes: 0
      });
      $scope.body = '';
    };
}]);

.controller('MainCtrl', [ '$scope', 'posts',
function($scope, posts){
    $scope.posts = posts.posts; 
  $scope.addPost= function(){
    if(!$scope.title || $scope.title === '') { alert("Field can't left blank"); return; }
    $scope.posts.push({
    title: $scope.title ,
    link: $scope.link,  
    upvotes: 0,
    comments: [
    { author: 'Joe', body: 'Cool post!', upvotes: 0 },
    { author: 'Bob', body: 'Great idea but everything is wrong!', upvotes: 0 }
    ]
    });
    $scope.title='';
    $scope.link='';
  };
  $scope.incrementUpvotes= function(post){
    post.upvotes += 1;
  };

}]);
```

Any idea what i am doing wrong?

`

Comment: When you are saying, app is not running. Are you getting any console errors, or whats happening?

Comment: I simply got a blank page. I don't know how to check on console.

Comment: Can you press F12. And then in dev tool you can find console. Then refresh the page again and check if you get some errors there.

Comment: It gives the error unexpected token. The error occurs in the js file where i had made the second controller named MainCtrl. I checked that line and i think that everying is alright their.

Comment: Ah! gotcha. You are chaining the controllers, you have added semicolon after `PostsCtrl`, which breaks the chaining. Remove the semicolon, everything should work fine.

Comment: I got the post page but still it gives the error on adding the comments to the post and the error is "TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined at l.$scope.addComment ".

Comment: You have written `$scope.post.comments.push`. But i don't see `$scope.post.comments` being declared/initialized anywhere. As, you need to initialize an object manually, it will not do it automatically.

Comment: how will i initialize the object manually? I don't know it.

Comment: Like this: `$scope.post.comments={};`

Comment: Wait, push means its an array. So, initialize like this: `$scope.post.comments=[];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below app.js. I have removed the semicolon.

```
angular.module('flapperNews', ['ui.router'])
.config([
'$stateProvider',
'$urlRouterProvider',
function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/home',
      templateUrl: '/home.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl'
    });

    $stateProvider
    .state('posts', {
      url: '/posts/{id}',
      templateUrl: '/posts.html',
      controller: 'PostsCtrl'
    });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
}])

.factory('posts', [function(){
  var o = {
    posts: [
      {title: 'post 1', link: 'link1',upvotes: 5},
      {title: 'post 2', link: 'link2',upvotes: 2},
      {title: 'post 3', link: 'link3',upvotes: 15},
      {title: 'post 4', link: 'link4',upvotes: 9},
      {title: 'post 5', link: 'link5',upvotes: 4}
    ]   
  };
  return o;
}])

.controller('PostsCtrl', [
'$scope',
'$stateParams',
'posts',
function($scope, $stateParams, posts){
    $scope.post = posts.posts[$stateParams.id];
    $scope.addComment = function(){
      if($scope.body === '') { return; }
      $scope.post.comments.push({
        body: $scope.body,
        author: 'user',
        upvotes: 0
      });
      $scope.body = '';
    };
}])

.controller('MainCtrl', [ '$scope', 'posts',
function($scope, posts){
    $scope.posts = posts.posts; 
  $scope.addPost= function(){
    if(!$scope.title || $scope.title === '') { alert("Field can't left blank"); return; }
    $scope.posts.push({
    title: $scope.title ,
    link: $scope.link,  
    upvotes: 0,
    comments: [
    { author: 'Joe', body: 'Cool post!', upvotes: 0 },
    { author: 'Bob', body: 'Great idea but everything is wrong!', upvotes: 0 }
    ]
    });
    $scope.title='';
    $scope.link='';
  };
  $scope.incrementUpvotes= function(post){
    post.upvotes += 1;
  };

}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
       <head>
          <title>Angular JS Includes</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
          <style>
             table, th , td {
                border: 1px solid grey;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                padding: 5px;
             }

             table tr:nth-child(odd) {
                background-color: #f2f2f2;
             }

             table tr:nth-child(even) {
                background-color: #ffffff;
             }
          </style>

       </head>
       <body ng-app = "mainApp">
          <h2>AngularJS Sample Application</h2>
          <div  ng-controller = "studentController">

             <table>
                <tr>
                   <th>Name</th>
                   <th>Roll No</th>
                   <th>Percentage</th>
                </tr>

                <tr ng-repeat = "student in students">
                   <td>{{ student.Name }}</td>
                   <td>{{ student.RollNo }}</td>
                   <td>{{ student.Percentage }}</td>
                </tr>
             </table>
          </div>
         <div  ng-controller="employeeController">
           <table>
                <tr>
                   <th>EmpName</th>
                   <th>EmpID</th>
                   <th>Salary</th>
                </tr>

                <tr ng-repeat = "employee in employees">
                   <td>{{ employee.EmpName }}</td>
                   <td>{{ employee.EmpID }}</td>
                   <td>{{ employee.Salary }}</td>
                </tr>
             </table>
          </div>       
          <script>
    var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []);

    mainApp.controller('studentController', function($scope,$http) {
       var url = "data.txt";

                $http.get(url).success( function(response) {
                   $scope.students = response;
                });
    });

    mainApp.controller('employeeController', function($scope,$http) {
      var url1 = "empdata.txt";

                $http.get(url1).success( function(response1) {
                   $scope.employees = response1;
                });
    });
    </script>


       </body>
    </html>

<make a file with data like below data.txt>
[
   {
      "Name" : "Mahesh Parashar",
      "RollNo" : 101,
      "Percentage" : "80%"
   },

   {
      "Name" : "Dinkar Kad",
      "RollNo" : 201,
      "Percentage" : "70%"
   },

   {
      "Name" : "Robert",
      "RollNo" : 191,
      "Percentage" : "75%"
   },

   {
      "Name" : "Julian Joe",
      "RollNo" : 111,
      "Percentage" : "77%"
   }
]

<make a file with data like below empdata.txt>
[
   {
      "EmpName" : "Mahesh Parashar",
      "EmpID" : 101,
      "Salary" : "80000"
   },

   {
      "EmpName" : "Dinkar Kad",
      "EmpID" : 201,
      "Salary" : "70000"
   },

   {
      "EmpName" : "Robert",
      "EmpID" : 191,
      "Salary" : "75000"
   },

   {
      "EmpName" : "Julian Joe",
      "EmpID" : 111,
      "Salary" : "77000"
   }
]
```

Comment: This is an simple example, where I have used 2 controller in a single view. I am reading data using ajax from external files.